# Calling Javascript function from Laravel controller and return data

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, firebase-authentication

I want to call a *firebase* auth function (which is in Javascript) from my controller and I want the returned `token` back in my controller, but I do not know how to proceed.

I know how to post `ajax` request to controller and get data back, however I don't know how to make a request the other way around.

I would be thankful if you can put me and other future users in right direction.

Comment: PHP cannot call to Javascript. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13840431/476. What you want is a PHP API to talk to Firebase, if such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not going to work.

You know a webserver is always supposed to be online. That way, you can always make a request.

A client-side (user), does **not** need, and isn't always online. If they close the browser window, you can't interact with them anymore. The server would have a hard time checking what user just went down, out of the thousands of users you have.

Making a call to a webserver is possible, but making a call to a client is not.

There are, next to that reason, security issues if you would be able to make a request to the client-side.

What you should probably do, is make a seperate request for the authentication token from Javascript, make Laravel call the Firebase AUTH server and then return the token it received.

---

**update**

It is possible to make requests to a client using HTTP2, by using [server-push](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/guide-http2-server-push/). To do that properly, especially with an authentication token, you will need some experience in building webservices and security.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a server side language and Javascript is client side. You cannot javascript on server and vice-versa. If you just need to generate JWT token, there are PHP libraries available for that already. But if you really want to execute javascript on server, that I think is not the case, you'll have to use [nodejs](http://nodejs.org)