# Laravel 5 : including javascript files

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.4

First off, I have to precise that I'm quite new to Laravel and that I have a lot to learn.

In one of my controller I need to call a Javascript function. To do so, I simply

```
echo "<script>triggerPixel();</script>";
```

I'm just unsure about where to store my Javascript file containing that function.

From what I got for the moment is that I should use elixir to add a file with something like this in the gulpfile.js :

```
mix.scripts('myscript.js');
```

Is this the right way to do it or should I simply add a file in resources/assets/javascripts ? 
I'm a bit lost and some explanation would be welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: if you're new to laravel, I highly suggest all of these videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwAKR305CRO-Q90J---jXVzbOd4CDRbVx

Comment: When you call any javascript function or include js its not work. You should have to include all the js in footer before </body> tag end.

Answer (score 2):

Put your actual .js file inside public/js folder

and then, put all your js reference in one file, for example footer.blade.php inside the resources/views folder.

Inside footer.blade.php :

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and then just call the footer inside one of your blade view using: `@include ('footer')`

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.
The problem is that I'm not using a view, I'm only using a controller to process something and during that process I need to call my JS file.

Comment: This is one of the article saying that you should not call a javascript function inside controller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879258/calling-javascript-function-from-laravel-controller-and-return-data